# Can't start chrome from powershell.. any ideas

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I opened this because my testing using karma wasn't working properly to start up chrome and run the tests. I was getting a black screen in a non-responsive chrome session when I tried.

I've since learned that karma probably had nothing to do with my problem. It looks like Chrome doesn't work when launched from powershell period.

```
$ & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
```

Will launch the corrupt chrome session.

So, I'm guessing karma has nothing to do with it. It looks like a chrome/powershell issue.

Any ideas?

Powershell (%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) and 64 bit chrome.

Comment: Noticed that chrome in general isn't running properly from my powershell window.

Comment: What is the `$` in your code snippet? That's a bash prompt sign, not a PowerShell one - unless you've customised it

Comment: Unless you're using a 32-bit OS, that's not 32-bit PowerShell.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I was probably wrong but I'm not sure there's an easy way to check the about of powershell. I just assumed that it was running out of sys32, so 32 bit (%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - possibly true. Posh~git maybe? I know that I've launched several apps successfully that way. And like I said Chrome launches, just not successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot to see if actually starting the process results in a different behavior.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Comment: Same result. Black screened chrome.

Comment: And if you start the exe from that directory by double-clicking on it? @Chris

Comment: Works fine from double clicking in the directory, being invoked in webstorm, powershell(x86), desktop shortcut etc. All of those are working fine and open chrome with my google as my homepage.

Comment: `powershell(x86)` is it x86 chrome? @Chris

Comment: Nope, Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)